# How can I create a CSV file with PHP that preserves the Japanese characters?

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding, character

Below is my code snippet for creating and downloading the CSV file from the browser.

```
$input_array[] = ['注文日時', '受注番号',];
$input_array[] = ['2015-09-30', 'INV-00001',];

    /** open raw memory as file, no need for temp files, be careful not to run out of memory thought */
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    /** loop through array  */
    foreach ($input_array as $line) {
        /** default php csv handler **/
        fputcsv($f, $line, ',');
    }
    /** rewrind the "file" with the csv lines **/
    fseek($f, 0);

    /** modify header to be downloadable csv file **/
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="my_csv_file.csv";');

    /** Send file to browser for download */
    fpassthru($f);

    die();
```

When I open the created/downloaded CSV file, the Japanese characters become the weird characters. What is not yet correct in my code snippet? How can I preserve the Japanese characters when creating the CSV file?

Comment: It works perfectly your code, I don't see any problem: Here is the result of the downloaded CSV file: `注文日時,受注番号
2015-09-30,INV-00001`

Comment: I noticed that excel is being a jerk here, standard text editors are fine. Edit: See http://superuser.com/questions/280603/how-to-set-character-encoding-when-opening-excel

Comment: Is there anyway to create the CSV with the right Unicode Characters Set selected without selecting it on Excel or Open Calc, because my users do not know that they need to do that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add a Byte Order Mark with a simple `echo` directly before writing the first line if you want to force any program to interpret the file as UTF-8 encoding:

```
$input_array[] = ['注文日時', '受注番号',];
$input_array[] = ['2015-09-30', 'INV-00001',];
echo "\xEF\xBB\xBF";/// Byte Order Mark HERE!!!!

    /** open raw memory as file, no need for temp files, be careful not to run out of memory thought */
    $f = fopen('php://memory', 'w');
    /** loop through array  */
    foreach ($input_array as $line) {
        /** default php csv handler **/
        fputcsv($f, $line, ',');
    }
    /** rewrind the "file" with the csv lines **/
    fseek($f, 0);

    /** modify header to be downloadable csv file **/
    header('Content-Encoding: UTF-8');
    header('Content-Type: application/csv; charset=UTF-8');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachement; filename="my_csv_file.csv";');

    /** Send file to browser for download */
    fpassthru($f);

    die();
```

Alternatively select `Unicode Character set` when you import it with Excel or Open Calc, otherwise opening it directly with notepad/textedit/etc there is no problem
[image: Importing]

Comment: Is there anyway to create the CSV with the right Unicode Characters Set selected without selecting it on Excel or Open Calc, because my users do not know that they need to do that.

Comment: Yes the Byte Order Mark does the magic. Thank you so much Gabriel Rodriguez. You just saved my days.

Comment: Good to know that!...Your Welcome

Comment: save my day too.. Thank you @GabrielRodriguez :)

Comment: Your welcome @AirfulShishir I didn't remember this lol....I totally forgot this(so much information these days) I problably would end up finding my own answer online if some day I wanted to do this because by that time I would probably forget it lol...