# Creating CSV file in PHP with Japanese characters and emailing, characters getting converted to?

Tags: php, csv, character-encoding, cjk

I have a page that when visited performs a SQL query and creates a CSV with the results and then emails the results to me.

However the japanese characters from the DB aren't being encoded properly and the CSV file i receive just has ? in place of each of the Japanese characters.

I have tried changing the "Content-Encoding", "Content-Transfer-Encoding", "Content-Type" to get a setting that works but no matter what I try i still only see ?? where there should be 東京

This is my code that generates the CSV on the fly and sends it.

```
$headers = "From: ".$email_from;


$random_hash = md5(date('r', time())); 
$mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$random_hash}x";


$headers .= "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";


$email_message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" .
"--{$mime_boundary}\n" .
"Content-Type:text/html; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8\n\n" .
$this->email_html_msg . "\n\n";

$files_attached_cnt = 0;
foreach ($this->arr_file_data AS $file_data) {

  $csv_file = $this->buildCSV($file_data, $mysqli);

  if ($csv_file != "") {
    $files_attached_cnt += 1;

    $data = $csv_file;

    $email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n";

    $email_message .= "Content-Type: application/csv; charset=\"UTF-8\"\n" .
    " name=\"{$file_data['csv_file_name']}\"\n" .
    "Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" .
    " filename=\"{$file_data['csv_file_name']}\"\n" .
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: UTF-8\n" .
    "Content-Encoding: UTF-8\n\n" .
    $data . "\n\n";
  }
}

$email_message .= "--{$mime_boundary}--\n";

$this->arr_file_data = array();

if ($this->debugFlag) {
  echo "FINISHED.";
}
```

Do I need to change my code completely or is there an encoding setting that would work in this instance?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I think this would be the answer for you.
[How can I create a CSV file with PHP that preserves the Japanese characters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32856716/how-can-i-create-a-csv-file-with-php-that-preserves-the-japanese-characters)

Answer (score 0):

found the answer was to set my sql query charset to utf8 before i actually started the query,

I added this

```
$mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
```

right after specifying the mysqli object.